# can you use a cycle path to bypass red lights?

Tags: legal, traffic, uk, london

Okay, so this is my issue.  On my commute home there is a spot where there is a light straight ahead, before the white line the cycle lane mergers with the path on the left.  Does this mean i can bypass the light, or am i jumping it if it is red?

[image: cycle path]

Comment: Check your local laws, but in most places, if the cycle path is built into the road you typically have to follow the flow signals (so you do have to stop at a red light), even though it's obviously safe to continue going.

Comment: That photo looks like a on-road bicycle lane to me, not a separated bicycle path/track...  Does it change up at the intersection?

Comment: @freiheit It does appear to change up at the intersection, just ahead of the street light. My guess is that you wouldn't have to stop anymore than pedestrians walking on the pavement (sidewalk) would, but I don't know British law. This is the view from the other side of the intersection: https://www.google.ca/maps/@51.415923,-0.187396,3a,75y,110.73h,80.2t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sfVRjrkbM5JRYOSKcvVLdng!2e0?hl=en

Comment: Hmm... I've changed my guess, you probably do have to stop at the advanced stop line (bike box) at the intersection, since you encounter this before the separated bike lane begins. Top down satellite view of the intersection: https://www.google.ca/maps/place/The+Nelson+Arms/@51.4159256,-0.18722,89m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x4876061df03ba47d:0x8dfabf1746e126a6?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for the comments. for clarification, the separated bike lane feeds directly out of the bike box - you do not cross any white lines to gain access to it. Also thank you for the appropriate tag edits, my first post...

Comment: The essential question is does the green cycle path turn off the road before or after the traffic light. If it's before it then it's ok to proceed.

Comment: Since I regularly see drivers getting this wrong, it's worth being clear: the light _only controls_ the stop line. If you don't cross a line, it doesn't matter where the light is or what colour it's showing.

Answer (score 4):

The light controls the stop line (and, if there is one, the advance stop line).

I can't tell from the streetview image, or from streetview itself or the satellite view, whether the cycle path moves from the road to the footway before the stop line or not.

If it does - you don't have to cross the line, and the light doesn't affect you (so long as you follow the cycle path onto the footway).

If it doesn't, or if you choose to stay on the road, you'll be crossing the line and controlled by the light.

Answer (score 3):

It depends totally on the design of the cycle way.  Here are three examples, all from the same intersection in Christchurch, New Zealand.  Note, we ride/drive on the left side of the road.

Satellite View 
https://www.google.co.nz/maps/@-43.4510769,172.6285092,165m/data=!3m1!1e3

[image]

1. Yes totally okay to bypass these lights.
2. Hell no!  its clearly obvious that this is a stop on red.
3. Ambiguous, and sometimes flouted by cyclists.  Personally I always stop on red here, but others might not.

---

- This shows the entrance ramp to #1.  Its coloured footpath ("colored sidewalk") showing clearly that the cyclist is intended to go up here.  The reason is that there are a lot of massive trucks turning left, and it has happened that turning trucks have flattened cyclists here and similar intersections elsewhere.

[image]

---

- ...and this is the exit showing clearly the expectation cycles will return to the road and not on the footpath/sidewalk.  Note the sign on the pole.

[image]

---

- Showing arrow #2 - its blatantly obvious this is a stop-on-red.  There's no way a bike would reasonably expect to cross here when the light is red.  Added for completeness.

[image]

---

- Finally, the ambiguous case #3   I personally always stop here but not all cyclists do, especially in a howling tailwind.  It may be possible to swerve up onto the footpath, but footpath riding is illegal here unless you're a postman or a small child or your wheels are smaller than 12" 
   Going straight forward through the red light would be running a red-light but we know some cyclists are a law unto themselves.

[image]

Comment: #3 is crystal clear. There's a stop line across the cycle lane and a traffic light. The red light means stop.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes which is why I stop.  But its commonly flouted by some cyclists, either by riding on or taking the footpath.

Comment: Sure, so it's not ambiguous: it's just commonly disregarded.